# PHP: mysql_query without waiting

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly I'm using the deprecated `mysql` functions (instead of `mysqli`) knowingly, so please do not tell me I should change to `mysqli`.

My question is: if I want to do an INSERT or UPDATE and continue processing the PHP script immediately, without waiting for MySQL to complete the task, can I use `mysql_unbuffered_query` (is that what is does?) or if not, how can I achieve that?

Comment: @MikeB, My question is actually whether mysql_unbuffered_query does this or not, so it is not the same question as that question does not answer my question.

Comment: Then your answer is no. mysql_unbuffer_query() still waits for the query to execute, it just doesn't go through the trouble of fetching the results. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: If you'le interested I wrote on how to execute queries in the background. Maybe it will help you or give you an idea: http://hancic.info/run-sql-queries-in-the-background-with-php

Comment: @jan You could have just posted the link to gearman here, would save a lot of time in reading your article that just says that you used it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [INSERT...DELAYED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html) for asynchronous insertions (1). I do not believe you can do asynchronous `UPDATE`'s without resorting to spawning another process (2).

(1) but is not available to `InnoDB` tables

(2) if sticking to the old `mysql` extension is an absolute requirement

Comment: Note that this will not work on all storage engines.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry to break this to you :)

If you use mysqli, with the mysqlnd driver, you can pass a `MYSQLI_ASYNC` option to the [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) method. Unbuffered queries do not help here.

Later on you can use the [poll()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and [reap_async_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to get to the result.

Comment: I knew someone would insist on mentioning `mysqi` even though I began my post specifically mentioning that I DO NOT CARE.

Comment: @Alasdair: Well I wanted to point it out, because that's the first place where true async queries are working. If you don't care about the security problems (which is pretty dumb), then this may still be a good reason to upgrade anyway.

Comment: @Alasdair Just as a hint, you can also use mysqli just in some small part, without updating your whole application to use it :)